# VBA - Populate Word Table from Excel as Dropdowns

Tags: excel, vba, import, ms-word

Let me begin by saying I'm not at all experienced with VBA; though I would like to be, I'm learning as I go, and subsequently, I don't know what I don't know. I'm having a hard time finding effective education material other than piecemealing things together, so any help there would be much appreciated.

I have a table I will be referring to as "Client Data". In this table, I have five cells that I need to auto-populate with data polled from a regularly updated excel spreadsheet: "Client ID", "Client Name", "Manager", "Support Contact", and "Subscription Date". "Client ID" should generate a drop-down box, and based on what a user selects in that drop-down the remaining cells should populate with the contextual data for that ID. Any advice or pointers on where I can start would help greatly.

Thank you!

**Edit**:

```
Sub Document_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim StrWkBkNm As String, StrWkShtNm As String, LRow As Long, i As Long
    StrWkBkNm = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Client List.xlsx"
    StrWkShtNm = "Client List"
    If Dir(StrWkBkNm) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With xlApp
        .Visible = False
        Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=StrWkBkNm, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
    With xlWkBk
    With .Worksheets(StrWkShtNm)
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ID")(1).DropdownListEntries.Clear
        For i = 2 To LRow
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ID")(1).DropdownListEntries.Add _
            Text:=Trim(.Range("A" & i))
        Next
    End With
        .Close False
    End With
        .Quit
    End With
        Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post some code that you have tried, we'll help you from there

Comment: Edited. The thing I read suggested this should be able to grab everything from A2 down in the excel and create the drop-down list on opening the doc, but whenever I open the doc (and yes, macros are enabled), nothing happens. Even then, I don't see how this will put the box anywhere specific.

Comment: Have you set the reference to Microsoft Excel in VBA?

Comment: Tools > References > Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, correct? If so, yes.

Comment: The drop down list control already exists in the word document?

Comment: You could implement a [user form](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/populate_userForm_listbox_or_combobox.html)

Comment: No, the control is not present. I'll try the user form though, thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16330-how-import-list-excel-into-drop-down-3.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @macropod - apologies. Any leads on where I can look to handle multiple entries? Some of the data I need to pull, for example, has a unique ID but multiple IDs may have the same "manager" attached, and I need to be able to pull the managers as well.

Comment: @Damiano. I have already answered that at MS Office Forums. Which part of "Entries in a ContentControl Dropdown must be unique" don't you understand? Clearly, if you need to assign the same manager to different IDs, you'll need a different structure for handling the manager names. You might, for example, pad the 2nd & subsequent instances with spaces that can be removed via Trim for further processing, or you might store them in a Document Variable alongside the corresponding ID for lookup purposes. It's up to you.

Comment: First, you don't need to be so aggressive. I would remind you I'm new to all this, don't necessarily know the terms the "experts" do, and would hope for the same patience I would grant someone else learning something for the first time. Since I assume we're grown adults and can speak like mature individuals, I was looking for the second half of your statement. Yes, I know a combo box can't have duplicates. I have / had no idea of other options to trim unwanted results from the source, barring creating another table and referencing that, and that's what I was trying to find out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is the VBA code for making autocomplete dropdown
and to populate other cell according to selected dropdown 
you can simply use the following excel formula-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,K2:L8,2,),"") 

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr

    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
            End If
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        xCombox.Activate
        Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what that first line is doing? I know vlookup is supposed to be a table value return, and maybe it's because the morning coffee hasn't kicked in yet, but I'm not sure I follow the use here.

Comment: use the following code to populate your excel cell using with autocomplete and use the formula to grab the data adjacent to your selected item for drop down iferror will not through any error if you leave cell blank. And if you're using latest excel version you can put your data into a table so if you add some entries to your list it will automatically take those to the formula.